# Python .transpose() gets error while transforming dictionary data

Tags: python, pandas

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'transpose'

I have been trying to extract cells as dictionary(from pandas dataframe) and trying to join with existing data

for example , I have csv file which contains two columns `id`,`device_type`.each cell in `device_type` column contains dictionary data. i have trying to split and add with original data.

[image]

And trying to do something like below.

[image]

```
import json
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('D:\\1. Work\\csv.csv',header=0)
sf = df.head(12)
sf['visitor_home_cbgs'].fillna("{}", inplace = True).transpose()
```

-- csv file sample

```
ID,device_type
3c30ee03047b478,{"060379800281":11,"061110053031":5,"060372062002":5}
f5d639a64a88496099,{}
```

-- looks for output like below

```
id,device_type,ttype,tvalue
3c30ee03047b478,{"060379800281":11,"061110053031":5,"060372062002":5},"060379800281",11
3c30ee03047b478,{"060379800281":11,"061110053031":5,"060372062002":5},"061110053031",5
3c30ee03047b478,{"060379800281":11,"061110053031":5,"060372062002":5},"060372062002",5
f5d639a64a88496099,{},NIL,NIL
```

Comment: fillna function is returning nothing i.e. None and you are trying to call transpose function on a None object. That's why this error is showing up.

Answer (score 1):

avoid inplace=True

```
sf['visitor_home_cbgs'].fillna("{}").transpose()
```

when you give `inplace=True`, it converts the same dataframe and returns null.
If you want to use `inplace=True`, then do like below

```
sf['visitor_home_cbgs'].fillna("{}", inplace=True)
sf.transpose()
```

#### To create rows from column values

One solution it to iterate through dataframe rows and create new dataframe with desired columns and values.

```
import json
def extract_JSON(row):
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'device_type', 'ttype', 'tvalue'])
    device_type = row['device_type']
    dict = json.loads(device_type)
    for key in dict:
        df2.loc[len(df2)] = [row['ID'], row['device_type'], key, dict[key]]
    if df2.empty:
        df2.loc[0] = [row['ID'], row['device_type'], '', '']
    return df2
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'device_type', 'ttype', 'tvalue'])
for _, row in df.iterrows():
    df3 = df3.append(extract_JSON(row))
df3
```

Comment: is it possible to split disctionary cell into number of columns ? in my example 3 rows ?. i have update question with sample data